# Compare if a date is two months bigger than other with Python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I've been trying for a while use python to compare if a date is two months bigger than other date.

Has anyone an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

dateEfec = "01/01/2016"
dateBase = "01/03/2016"

effectivedate = time.strptime(dateEfec,"%d/%m/%Y")
baseline = time.strptime(dateBase, "%d/%m/%Y")

calc = effectivedate > baseline + relativedelta(months=2)
print(calc)
```

I'm getting this error:

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "relativedelta") to tuple

Comment: "01/03/2016" is Exactly 2 months after "01/01/2016" but you are checking if it's bigger than 2 months, which is not. What are you getting as result?

Comment: your code is missing imports. please add them so we can run your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timedelta` has no attribute 'month' - because a month is an ambiguous quantity, it can have 28-31 days. Use [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) instead.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

dateEfec = "01/03/2016"
dateBase = "01/01/2016"

effectivedate = datetime.strptime(dateEfec,"%d/%m/%Y")
baseline = datetime.strptime(dateBase, "%d/%m/%Y")

calc = effectivedate >= baseline + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=2)
print(calc)
# True
```

Note: I've modified the example so it makes for a better illustration.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. That's what I'm trying to do, I already edited my post. But, I'm getting this error: TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "relativedelta") to tuple

Comment: @pythonnoobie since my example code runs fine, did you make sure your imports are correct?

Comment: hey, I erased the whole code and wrote as you sent and it worked! thanks a lot (: